# Do stacks on Mejai's Soulstealer round up or down on death?

Tags: league-of-legends

For example, if I die with 5 stacks do I end up at 2 or 3 stacks?

Comment: http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=467768

Comment: http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=31082

Comment: @ColinD Why don't you use that information and place it in an answer?

Comment: @Joetjah The links seem to contradict each other somewhat. I would not treat either of those sources as authoritative enough to be an actual answer.

Comment: When you have 20 and you die you got 14 stacks 20* 2/3 = 13,333 ==> Round up  ///// 5 * 2/3  = 3.333 => 4 stacks

Answer (score 3):

Did some experimentation and here is what I found:
It seems like every stack count but 20 rounds based on the decimal. When I died with 20 stacks, it rounded to 14 stacks instead of 13.

20 stacks goes to 14 stacks. 20 * (2/3) => 13.333 this result rounds up on death, I'm not sure why so I thoroughly tested the other numbers
[image]
[image]

---

19  stacks goes to 13 stacks. 19 * (2/3) => 12.6667 rounds to 13.

18 stacks goes to 12 stacks. 20 * (2/3) => 12

17 stacks to 11 stacks. 17 * (2/3) => 11.333 rounds to 11.
[image]
[image]

---

15 stacks to 10 stacks. 15 * (2/3) => 10

14 stacks goes to 9 stacks. 14 * (2/3) => 9.333 rounds to 9.
[image]
[image]

---

10 stacks goes to 7 stacks. 10 * (2/3) => 6.66667 rounds to 7.
[image]
[image]

---

8 Stacks goes to 5 stacks 8 * (2/3) => 5.333333 rounds to 5.

5 Stacks goes to 3 stacks. 5 * (2/3) => 3.3333 rounds to 3. 
[image]
[image]

---

4 Stacks goes to 3 stacks. 4 * (2/3) => 3.3333 rounds to 3.

3 Stacks goes to 1 stack. 3 * (2/3) => 1

2 Stacks goes to 1 stack. 2 * (2/3) => 1.3333 rounds to 1.

So, besides the odd rounding with 20 stacks, it works as you would expect. I have some other pictures I can insert, but I didn't bother inserting the easily divisible stacks.

Comment: I would love to say no Bots or Fizzes were hurt in the making of this answer, but well...

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm at work so i can't provide you any source but my experience :-D

When you have 20 and you die you got 14 stacks 20* 2/3 = 13,333 ==> Round up

So : 5 * 2/3  = 3.333 => 4 stacks

;-)